# pandas iterrows into a dictionary and creating a new dataframe not working

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe (about 28000+ rows, and 61 columns)

the original data columns are:

```
data.columns
Index(['count_id', 'count_date', 'location_id', 'lanes', 'is_oneway',
       'location', 'lng', 'lat', 'centreline_type', 'centreline_id', 'px',
       'time_start', 'time_end', 'sb_cars_r', 'sb_cars_t', 'sb_cars_l',
       'nb_cars_r', 'nb_cars_t', 'nb_cars_l', 'wb_cars_r', 'wb_cars_t',
       'wb_cars_l', 'eb_cars_r', 'eb_cars_t', 'eb_cars_l', 'sb_truck_r',
       'sb_truck_t', 'sb_truck_l', 'nb_truck_r', 'nb_truck_t', 'nb_truck_l',
       'wb_truck_r', 'wb_truck_t', 'wb_truck_l', 'eb_truck_r', 'eb_truck_t',
       'eb_truck_l', 'sb_bus_r', 'sb_bus_t', 'sb_bus_l', 'nb_bus_r',
       'nb_bus_t', 'nb_bus_l', 'wb_bus_r', 'wb_bus_t', 'wb_bus_l', 'eb_bus_r',
       'eb_bus_t', 'eb_bus_l', 'nx_peds', 'sx_peds', 'ex_peds', 'wx_peds',
       'nx_bike', 'sx_bike', 'ex_bike', 'wx_bike', 'nx_other', 'sx_other',
       'ex_other', 'wx_other'],
      dtype='object')
```

I am trying to create a new data frame with only the required columns

First I create a dictionary with the column headers:

```
row_dict = {
    'location_id': 0,
    'year': 0,
    'month': 0,
    'day': 0,
    'time_start_hour': 0,
    'time_start_min': 0,
    'time_end_hour': 0,
    'time_end_min': 0,
    'num_lanes': 0,
    'is_oneway': 0,
    'is_weekend': 0,
    'is_holiday': 0,
    'nx': 0,
    'sx': 0,
    'ex': 0,
    'wx': 0,
    'nb_r': 0,
    'nb_t': 0,
    'nb_l': 0,
    'sb_r': 0,
    'sb_t': 0,
    'sb_l': 0,
    'eb_r': 0,
    'eb_t': 0,
    'eb_l': 0,
    'wb_r': 0,
    'wb_t': 0,
    'wb_l': 0
}
```

Then i create an empty list where i will store each row: `data_list = []`

Then i loop over the original dataframe and take the relevant info into my dictionary. I append the dicitonary into the list. And finally I convert the list to a dataframe:

```
def getTime(time):
    time = time.split(' ')[1].split('-')[0]
    hour, minute, _ = time.split(':')
    return float(hour), float(minute)

def isWeekend(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').weekday() > 4

def isHoliday(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') in holidays.CA()

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    row_dict['location_id'] = row['location_id']
    row_dict['year'], row_dict['month'], row_dict['day'] = row['count_date'].split('-')
    row_dict['time_start_hour'], row_dict['time_start_min'] = getTime(row['time_start'])
    row_dict['time_end_hour'], row_dict['time_end_min'] = getTime(row['time_end'])
    row_dict['num_lanes'] = row['lanes']
    row_dict['is_oneway'] = row['is_oneway']
    row_dict['is_weekend'] = isWeekend(row['count_date'])
    row_dict['is_holiday'] = isHoliday(row['count_date'])

    row_dict['nx'] = float(row['nx_peds']) + float(row['nx_bike']) + float(row['nx_other'])
    row_dict['sx'] = float(row['sx_peds']) + float(row['sx_bike']) + float(row['sx_other'])
    row_dict['ex'] = float(row['ex_peds']) + float(row['ex_bike']) + float(row['ex_other'])
    row_dict['wx'] = float(row['wx_peds']) + float(row['wx_bike']) + float(row['wx_other'])

    row_dict['nb_r'] = float(row['nb_cars_r']) + float(row['nb_truck_r']) + float(row['nb_bus_r'])
    row_dict['nb_t'] = float(row['nb_cars_t']) + float(row['nb_truck_t']) + float(row['nb_bus_t'])
    row_dict['nb_l'] = float(row['nb_cars_l']) + float(row['nb_truck_l']) + float(row['nb_bus_l'])
    
    row_dict['sb_r'] = float(row['sb_cars_r']) + float(row['sb_truck_r']) + float(row['sb_bus_r'])
    row_dict['sb_t'] = float(row['sb_cars_t']) + float(row['sb_truck_t']) + float(row['sb_bus_t'])
    row_dict['sb_l'] = float(row['sb_cars_l']) + float(row['sb_truck_l']) + float(row['sb_bus_l'])
    
    row_dict['eb_r'] = float(row['eb_cars_r']) + float(row['eb_truck_r']) + float(row['eb_bus_r'])
    row_dict['eb_t'] = float(row['eb_cars_t']) + float(row['eb_truck_t']) + float(row['eb_bus_t'])
    row_dict['eb_l'] = float(row['eb_cars_l']) + float(row['eb_truck_l']) + float(row['eb_bus_l'])
    
    row_dict['wb_r'] = float(row['wb_cars_r']) + float(row['wb_truck_r']) + float(row['wb_bus_r'])
    row_dict['wb_t'] = float(row['wb_cars_t']) + float(row['wb_truck_t']) + float(row['wb_bus_t'])
    row_dict['wb_l'] = float(row['wb_cars_l']) + float(row['wb_truck_l']) + float(row['wb_bus_l'])
    data_list.append(row_dict)
finalData = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

However, when i do this and look into the dataframe, i only see one row repeated 28000+ times.
But when i only print the rows using iterrows, it prints everything properly:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row['location_id']
```

Am i doing something wrong or am i not using the function as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
I needed to copy the dictionary before appending it
fix is: `data_list.append(row_dict.copy())`